# Using JWT As authentication Protocol in Named Credentials for External Service

Tags: namedcredentials, jwt, external-services

As a part of my project work, I need to connect to Azure Logic App via External Service in Salesforce.
I know the prerequisite is to create Named Credentials first.

I have chosen following in setting up Named Credentials

Identity Type: Named Principal
Authentication Protocol: JWT

Certificate: Here I am confused whether it should be Salesforce Generated Certificate or Azure Generated??
Issuer: What value needs to be put here? SF Documentation says **Specify who issued the JWT using a case-sensitive string** I really don't get it.
Named Principal Subject??
Audiences:??

I could not find good example where Named Credentials with JWT gets used to call Azure.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Certificate**

The certificate should be generated on Azure and imported into Salesforce.

> One consideration is Salesforce only accepts certificates in the `.jks` format. You will import using the certificate and key management. Check the screenshot below

[image]

If you have this in any other format you will need to translate it to .jks format using open SSL.

**2. Issuer: What value needs to be put here?**

This is provided again by Azure services. Any JWT system that accepts JWT requests provides an Issuer value. It's generally a string value.

For example if you were connecting to Salesforce from another system, this will be `clientId` of the connected app.

**3. Named Principal Subject**

This is also provided by Azure services. Usually, this is a username or a unique identity

For example if you were connecting to Salesforce from a third party system this is username of the user you are using to connect to Salesforce.

**4. Audiences**

This is usually the url shared by the service. Azure external service if this supports JWT then this will be documented.

For example if you were connecting to Salesforce from a third party system this will be `https://login.salesforce.com`

Comment: Thanks @mohit for a quick answer, do we need to configure Connected App as well in Salesforce as well? if I need to use named credentials with JWT

Comment: No, you do not need to. The examples I gave were for another way round let's say you wanted to reach into Salesforce from a third-party service.